# Upgrade to mavericks and incompatible printer drivers

Tags: printer, osx-mavericks

After Mavericks upgrade, my Brother 1040 and HP H470 no longer work. I can see them in printer list, jobs are sent, but nothing happens at the printer.
I've installed latest available drives.
Is mavericks so different that print drivers all need to be upgraded?

After 'upgrade' I now need to print via my old windows visa desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the answer is yes. You can find new drivers at:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3669

Unfortunately that does not seem to solve the problem. I have Samsung printers. I can open the print queue from System Preferences, print a test page from the Printer menu and it comes out OK, but any page I print from the print dialog acts like its printing but then nothing comes out.